# a system of nonlinear equations (power sum) 

Tags: linear-algebra

greetings . is there a general method-algorithm to solve the following system !?

$\sum_{n=1}^{m} {x_{n}}^{j}= {k}_{j} $

$j=1,2,...,m$

$k_{j}$ are constants

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution of this system are  ALL m roots of the polynomial equation P(x) = 0 in ONE variable.
Where P(x) is defined as follows.

Power sum related to elementary symmetric functions by the so-called Newton formulas.
$\sigma_i = Newton (p_i)$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities

So define $c_i= Newton(k_j)$.

And write polynom $P(x) = \sum_i c_i x^i$

Its zeros are yours numbers $x_i$.

To solve polynomial equation you may use Newton method or any other method.

Comment: thank you , i was aware of this method . http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=568099 . i was hoping for a different one . 

Comment:  For practical solution I think this is the best method. Any way I think any method which will take into account specific structure of this system will be equivalent. Otherwise you may use general method like consider min( \sum_i |F_i(x)-k_i|^2 ) - this can be attacked by steepest descent.

Comment: For future reference, when you ask a question here, you should tell us what you already know, so people don't waste their time telling you things you already know. 